# Perforce client has a static view that will be overwritten

Tags: perforce

I am following the streams tiny tutorial:

http://www.perforce.com/blog/110324/streams-tiny-tutorial

When I issue this command:

```
p4 workspace -s -S //Ace/MAIN
```

It complains that client localhost does not exist

> P4HOST is localhost via p4 set for the current user.

If I use:

```
p4 -c localhost workspace -s -S //Ace/MAIN
```

It complains that localhost is a static view that will be overwritten if I use -f.

What is a static view?

Also, I don't want my workspace to be called localhost.

So, I used p4 workspace without arguments to create a spec that gives it a meaningful workspace name. After that:

```
p4 workspace -s -S //Ace/MAIN
```

Still complains that client localhost does not exist. Why is that?

If I use:

```
p4 workspace -s -S //Ace/MAIN meaningful-client-name
```

It complains that meaningful-client-name is a static view that will be overwritten if I use -f.

Again, what is a static view?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an answer to why I get the warning:

http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/2749-cant-switch-to-a-stream-workspace/page__hl__static+view

Perforce is warning it's clobbering a non-stream view. The rest of my post should be a separate question, I think